# What is the source of shloka: "Daivadhinam Jagat sarvam, mantradhinam tu daivatam Tan mantram brahmanadhinam, brahmano mama devata"

Tags: identification-request, shloka, source

What is the source of shloka:

> "Daivadhinam Jagat sarvam, mantradhinam tu daivatam
> Tan mantram brahmanadhinam, brahmano mama devata"

Alternatively

> देवाधीनं जगत सर्वे, मंत्राधीना च देवता, ते मंत्रा ब्राह्मणाधीना, तस्मात् ब्राह्मण

Comment: I can't be certain but I found an archive page stating a similar mantra, which was part of a brahmana in the Sama Veda.